# Count in records in xml with condition using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

HI I am creating an XSLT file for transforming XML. I want to count records with condition

```
<Body>
    <BankAccountTable class="entity">          
      <AccountNum>123456789</AccountNum>          
      <BankChequeTable class="entity">
        <AccountID>101</AccountID>
        <AmountCur>40.00</AmountCur>
        <ChequeStatus>Payment</ChequeStatus>            
        <VendTable class="entity">
          <AccountNum>1</AccountNum>              
        </VendTable>            
      </BankChequeTable>
      <BankChequeTable class="entity">
        <AccountID>101</AccountID>
        <AmountCur>45.00</AmountCur>            
        <ChequeStatus>Payment</ChequeStatus>            
        <VendTable class="entity">
          <AccountNum>2</AccountNum>              
        </VendTable>            
      </BankChequeTable>
      <BankChequeTable class="entity">
        <AccountID>101</AccountID>
        <AmountCur>45.00</AmountCur>            
        <ChequeStatus>Void</ChequeStatus>            
        <VendTable class="entity">
          <AccountNum>2</AccountNum>              
        </VendTable>            
      </BankChequeTable>          
    </BankAccountTable>
```

Now i want to count BankAccountTable records where ChequeStatus must equals to Payment can any one suggest how to achieve this. I am using Xsl:stylesheet version="1.0".
I am able to count all record by using this line of code:

---

```
<xsl:for-each select="/BankAccountTable"> <xsl:variable name="totalCount" select="count(child::BankChequeTable)"></xsl:variable>
```

---

but I want it with condition. for following example count must be equals to 2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can count the records like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="totalCount" select="count(Body/BankAccountTable/BankChequeTable[ChequeStatus='Payment'])"/>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZYrpt